# jQuery: Issues with combined click and hover functions

Tags: jquery

My webpage looks like that at the moment:

```js
// Hover Function

$("#cats_image").mouseover(function() {
  $("h1").text("Cats");
});

$("#dogs_image").mouseover(function() {
  $("h1").text("Dogs");
});

$("#ducks_image").mouseover(function() {
  $("h1").text("Ducks");
});

$("img").mouseout(function() {
  $("h1").text("Animals");
});


// Click Function

$("#cats_image").click(function() {
  $("h1").text("Cats");
  $("footer div").removeClass("show");
  $("#cats_text").addClass("show");
});

$("#dogs_image").click(function() {
  $("h1").text("Dogs");
  $("footer div").removeClass("show");
  $("#dogs_text").addClass("show");
});

$("#ducks_image").click(function() {
  $("h1").text("Dogs");
  $("footer div").removeClass("show");
  $("#ducks_text").addClass("show");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
}

main {}

img {
  max-width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

footer div {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <h1>Animals</h1>
</header>

<main>
  <img id="cats_image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Mackerel_tabby_cat_pair-Hisashi-01.jpg">
  <img id="dogs_image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/Two_puppies_dogs.jpg">
  <img id="ducks_image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/The_pair_of_ducks.jpg">
</main>

<footer>
  <div id="cats_text">Domestic cats are valued by humans for companionship and their ability to hunt rodents.</div>
  <div id="dogs_text">The coats of domestic dogs are of two varieties: "double" being familiar with dogs (as well as wolves) originating from colder climates, made up of a coarse guard.</div>
  <div id="ducks_text">Duck is the common name for numerous species in the waterfowl family Anatidae which also includes swans and geese.</div>
</footer>
```

The hover function looks perfect at first glance. But if you click for example one image, the title ("Cats", "Dogs", or "Ducks") should stay there, as long as you don't click another image. If you click in a white area (outside the images, and the text areas), it should look like nothing was clicked before (title: "Animals", and no footer text).

I tried a lot, and I am absolutely not sure how to go on. Could somebody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't work because you set the title as `Animals` in the mouseout event.
Meaning, you do need to set the global value for the title like the below code lines.

```js
let selected_animal = "Animals"

// Hover Function

$("#cats_image").mouseover(function() {
  $("h1").text("Cats");
});

$("#dogs_image").mouseover(function() {
  $("h1").text("Dogs");
});

$("#ducks_image").mouseover(function() {
  $("h1").text("Ducks");
});

$("img").mouseout(function() {
  $("h1").text(selected_animal);
});


// Click Function

$("#cats_image").click(function() {
  selected_animal = "Cats"
  $("h1").text("Cats");
  $("footer div").removeClass("show");
  $("#cats_text").addClass("show");
});

$("#dogs_image").click(function() {
  selected_animal = "Dogs"
  $("h1").text("Dogs");
  $("footer div").removeClass("show");
  $("#dogs_text").addClass("show");
});

$("#ducks_image").click(function() {
  selected_animal = "Ducks"
  $("h1").text("Ducks");
  $("footer div").removeClass("show");
  $("#ducks_text").addClass("show");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
}

main {}

img {
  max-width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

footer div {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <h1>Animals</h1>
</header>

<main>
  <img id="cats_image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Mackerel_tabby_cat_pair-Hisashi-01.jpg">
  <img id="dogs_image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/Two_puppies_dogs.jpg">
  <img id="ducks_image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/The_pair_of_ducks.jpg">
</main>

<footer>
  <div id="cats_text">Domestic cats are valued by humans for companionship and their ability to hunt rodents.</div>
  <div id="dogs_text">The coats of domestic dogs are of two varieties: "double" being familiar with dogs (as well as wolves) originating from colder climates, made up of a coarse guard.</div>
  <div id="ducks_text">Duck is the common name for numerous species in the waterfowl family Anatidae which also includes swans and geese.</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thaaaanks! Looks good! One thing is missing: If you click in the white area, the initial state should appear. Doing it with "$("*").click(function()" does not work, unfortunately. :/

Comment: For that, add a click event to the whole document resetting everything and tell the click events in your animal images to `event.stopPropagation();` that way the click won't bubble up the DOM and trigger the click on the body (e.g. use `$('body')`)